# Angular 6 - Remove ngClass

Tags: validation, angular6, ng-class

I have a profile page in my angular app where once the user is logged in, he can update his profile information. Profile page has got a basic information available for update to the user. All the values is pre-filled in the respective textbox.

My form structure is as follows:

```
<div class="col col-lg-6 col-md-6 pull-left pl-0">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FirstName" formControlName="FirstName" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.FirstName.errors }" value="{{ profileInfo.FirstName }}" />
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.FirstName.errors" class="help-block">
          <div *ngIf="f.FirstName.errors.required">* Required</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can check the value attribute that profileInfo.FirstName sets the value of the textbox. This way all the fields on the profile page is pre populated. But when user clicks on Submit button without updating any field, it validates all the fields and marks all the fields as Required until I don't focus each input manually.

What can I do to avoid such validation to take place even when the value in the textbox exists and is valid.

Answer (score 0):

When user click on submit button try to read form data. Then reactive form has feature that you can get the flag that form is valid or not.

console that value by this way .

```
console.log(this.form.isValid());
```

If you get true then you will never get red color on input. By this way you know that where you goes wrong. As you haven't give detail code , I just give path to fix and debug issue.